# Android Studio Emulator Error: "deleteSnapshot: for default_boot"

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device, snapshot

I installed Android Emulator and `Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image (API 28)` and configured a `AVD`, then ran it for first time. The emulator window showed and closed immediately and in Event Log, I see this error:

```
5:48 PM Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
5:48 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

This error occurs in both `Cold` and `Quick Boot`.

- *I already installed the `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM)`.*
- *I currently use `Android Studio 3.1.4`.*
- *I tried using `Wipe Data` and recreating the `AVD`, but nothing became affected.*

**What's wrong and how to fix this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was with my CPU. So I used [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) (that uses VirtualBox), it's much faster than AVD. I repeat it's very FAST. Now, I'm using Android 9 (Pie) on Genymotion.

I recommend Genymotion for those who have problems with AVD.

Answer (score 2):

Actualy I got similar error often:

`16:22  Emulator: D:\Data\Sdk\Android\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

16:22   Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

16:22   Emulator: qemu: unsupported keyboard cmd=0x84

16:22   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0`

I figured out it is good to make snapshot when you install new device(like google account etc.)

When the error occurrs again, then you need to edit device, Show advanced settings and select Boot from snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Dude I was having the same problem and solved doing the following:

I accessed Android Studio, went to the list of my AVDs and wiped the data with the "Wipe Data" function.

After that it went back to normal operation.

Hope this helps! = D

Answer (score 0):

If there is unused AVD's remove them,then Try to increase RAM size of the emulator and restart your android studio.

Comment: When I first installed HAXM, I set 1536 MB for maximum RAM and I couldn't increase RAM size of a AVD device to higher than 1536 MB. Then, I removed and reinstalled the HAXM and this time I set the maximum RAM size ans restarted AS. But I can't increase the RAM size to higher than 1536 MB, this means, reinstalling the HAXM with other Memory Limit, doesn't affect the first time I set the Memory Limit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Avast was the cause of the problem, I'm solve it deactivating avast's shields for 10 minutes, run the emulator (It runs well again but deleted all the previous apps installed), closed it, close android studio, reactivate the Avast's shield again and run android studio and the emulator works fine again now.